# How to draw straight lines in a restrictive area?

Tags: r, line

I have a spectral plot with 2 straight lines, which I made with the following commands:
(a is the slope from the left part of the spectrum, b the right. the boundary is 3200 Hz here)

```
a=0.009909
b=-0.003873

plot(spec, type="l", main...)

abline(a, col="orange")
abline(b, col="skyblue")
abline(v=3200, lty=2)
```

[image]

What I would like to do is to draw the orange line until 3200 Hz and the skyblue line from 3200 Hz like the following plot (roughly created by photoshop, sorry):

[image]

Is that with the function abline() possible? Or is there any way to do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: One issues is, how are your calls to `abline()` working? If `a` is as you claim a vector of length 1, the slope, and you don't specify `b` in the *same call* (where `b` is the intercept), you get an error - I just tried it. Logically this makes sense, the slope of the line is not enough to define where to draw the line. If you have the slope and intercept then you could evaluate `y <- b + (a * x)` where `x` is a regularly spaced set of values on interval you want. Then use `lines(x, y)`.

Comment: sorry I over-reduced my code. The slope came out from lm(), the first part of the code should be like:

`library(emu)`
`spec1=spec[,1000:3200]`
`spec2=spec[,3201:8000]`
`a=lm(spec1~trackfreq(spec1))`
`b=lm(spec2~trackfreq(spec2))`

but still thank you very much!

Comment: If you have the fitted model, just use `predict()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*edited to fix an error*

Here is a basic example that should be extendable to your data. It relies on generating the coefficients for the lines of best fit for each subset of data first using `glm` and then calling these in a `lines` statement.

```
test <- c(1.4, 2.3, 3.8, 3.6, 5.9, 5.4, 7.6, 7.4, 8.1, 8.7, 7.4, 6.9, 
5.4, 4.7, 2.7, 1.8, 1.1)

plot(test,type="l",ylim=c(0,12))
fit1 <- glm(test[1:8] ~ I(1:8))
fit2 <- glm(test[9:17] ~ I(1:9))

# ...$coefficients[2] is the slope, ...$coefficients[1] is the intercept
lines(1:9, 1:9 * fit1$coefficients[2] + fit1$coefficients[1],col="red")
lines(9:17,1:9 * fit2$coefficients[2] + fit2$coefficients[1],col="blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have the fitted models, then the best solution is to use the `predict()` method to generate predictions for a set of equally spaced points over the intervals of interest.

Using the data from @thelatemail's answer

```
df <- data.frame(y = c(1.4, 2.3, 3.8, 3.6, 5.9, 5.4, 7.6, 7.4, 8.1,
                       8.7, 7.4, 6.9, 5.4, 4.7, 2.7, 1.8, 1.1),
                 x = 1:17,
                 ind = rep(c(TRUE,FALSE), times = c(8,9)))

fit1 <- lm(y ~ x, data = df, subset = ind)
fit2 <- lm(y ~ x, data = df, subset = !ind)

## regions in a new data frame over which to predict
r1 <- data.frame(x = seq(from = 1, to = 8, length.out = 20))
r2 <- data.frame(x = seq(from = 9, to = 17, length.out = 20))

## predict
p1 <- predict(fit1, newdata = r1)
p2 <- predict(fit2, newdata = r2)

## add lines to plot
plot(y ~ x, data = df, type = "l")
lines(p1 ~ x, data = r1, col = "red")
lines(p2 ~ x, data = r2, col = "blue")
```

This gives

[image]

This is a more flexible way of doing what you want than writing out the equation by hand, and works with many types of model where they have a `predict()` method.